# How to control dash print output

Tags: python, plotly

I've made a dash and it showed as I want, my code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
    
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Branch': ['Hanoi','Hanoi','Hanoi','Hochiminh','Hochiminh','Hochiminh','Danang','Danang','Danang'],
                'Name': ['Sales','Card','Loan','Sales','Card','Loan','Sales','Card','Loan'],
                'KPI': [1000,1200,8000,1000,1200,8000,1000,1200,8000],
                'Complete' : [982,1015,7105,780,1120,7600,815,1150,6800]})
df3['Percent'] = ((df3['Complete']/df3['KPI'])*100).round(decimals=2)
    
app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
    
app.layout = html.Div([dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.H2('KPI Subplots',className='text-center text primary, mb-3'))),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([html.H5('Sales KPI',className='text-center'),
                    dcc.Graph(id='credit_fluctuation',figure={},style={'height':150}),
                    ],width={'size':1,"offset":0,'order':1},),            
                dbc.Col([html.H5('Card KPI',className='text-center'),
                    dcc.Graph(id='credit_fluctuation_2',figure={},style={'height':150}),
                    ],width={'size':1,"offset":0,'order':1}),
                dbc.Col([html.H5('Loan KPI',className='text-center'),
                    dcc.Graph(id='credit_fluctuation_3',figure={},style={'height':150}),
                    ],width={'size':1,"offset":0,'order':1}),   
                dbc.Col([html.H5('Drop Down',className='text-center'),
                    dcc.Dropdown(id='br_cd_2',placeholder="Please select branch code",
                                    options=[{'label':x,'value':x} for x in df3.sort_values('Branch')['Branch'].unique()],
                                    value='Select',
                                    multi=False,
                                    disabled=False,
                                    clearable=True,
                                    searchable=True),
                        ],width={'size':2,"offset":0,'order':1})
            ]),
    
    ])
    
@app.callback(
            Output(component_id='credit_fluctuation',component_property='figure'),
            [Input(component_id='br_cd_2',component_property='value')])
    
def build_graph(branch_cd):
    global dff
    if not branch_cd or 'Select' in branch_cd:
        dff = df3[(df3['Name']=="Sales")]
        dff = pd.pivot_table(dff,('KPI','Complete'),index=['Name',],aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
        dff['Percent'] = ((dff['Complete']/dff['KPI'])*100).round(decimals=2)
        val=dff.iloc[0,3]
        
    else:
        dff = df3[(df3['Branch']== branch_cd)]#.isin(branch_cd)
        dff = dff[(dff['Name']=='Sales')]
        val=dff.iloc[0,4]
        
    fig=go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['',''],
                              values=[val,100-val],
                              hole=0.85,
                              textinfo='none',
                              marker_colors=['rgb(113,209,145)','rgb(240,240,240)'],
                              )],
                 layout=go.Layout(annotations=[{'text':str(val)+"%",'x':0.5,'y':0.5,'font_size':20,'showarrow':False}],
                                 showlegend=False))
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=5,r=5,t=5,b=5))
    return fig
    
@app.callback(
            Output(component_id='credit_fluctuation_2',component_property='figure'),
            [Input(component_id='br_cd_2',component_property='value')])
    
def build_graph(branch_cd_2):
    global dff2
    if not branch_cd_2 or 'Select' in branch_cd_2:
            dff2 = df3[(df3['Name']=="Card")]
            dff2 = pd.pivot_table(dff2,('KPI','Complete'),index=['Name',],aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
            dff2['Percent'] = ((dff2['Complete']/dff2['KPI'])*100).round(decimals=2)
            val2=dff2.iloc[0,3]
        
    else:
            dff2 = df3[(df3['Branch']== branch_cd_2)]#.isin(branch_cd)
            dff2 = dff2[(dff2['Name']=='Card')]
            val2=dff2.iloc[0,4]
        
    fig_2=go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['',''],
                              values=[val2,100-val2],
                              hole=0.85,
                              textinfo='none',
                              marker_colors=['rgb(113,209,145)','rgb(240,240,240)'],
                              )],
                 layout=go.Layout(annotations=[{'text':str(val2)+"%",'x':0.5,'y':0.5,'font_size':20,'showarrow':False}],
                                 showlegend=False))
    fig_2.update_layout(margin=dict(l=5,r=5,t=5,b=5))
    return fig_2
    
@app.callback(
            Output(component_id='credit_fluctuation_3',component_property='figure'),
            [Input(component_id='br_cd_2',component_property='value')])
    
def build_graph(branch_cd_3):
    global dff3
    if not branch_cd_3 or 'Select' in branch_cd_3:
            dff3 = df3[(df3['Name']=="Loan")]
            dff3 = pd.pivot_table(dff3,('KPI','Complete'),index=['Name',],aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
            dff3['Percent'] = ((dff3['Complete']/dff3['KPI'])*100).round(decimals=2)
            val3=dff3.iloc[0,3]
        
    else:
            dff3 = df3[(df3['Branch']== branch_cd_3)]#.isin(branch_cd)
            dff3 = dff3[(dff3['Name']=='Loan')]
            val3=dff3.iloc[0,4]
        
    fig_3=go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['',''],
                              values=[val3,100-val3],
                              hole=0.85,
                              textinfo='none',
                              marker_colors=['rgb(113,209,145)','rgb(240,240,240)'],
                              )],
                 layout=go.Layout(annotations=[{'text':str(val3)+"%",'x':0.5,'y':0.5,'font_size':20,'showarrow':False}],
                                 showlegend=False))
    fig_3.update_layout(margin=dict(l=5,r=5,t=5,b=5))    
    return fig_3
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run_server(debug=False,port=8056)
```

This is the result:
[image]

But when I try to print it out, it was overlapped as attached picture.
[image]

So I would like to ask that is there any way to print dash same with this appearance. I tried to export to pdf but it was overlapped too. Please give me some suggestion.

Thank you.